# Test net environment URL clarification

Tags: node.js, ripple, cryptocurrency, xrp

Anyone suggest to test the Ripple(XRP) API environment URL link for transaction history by address wise.

I need test network address so now I am tried to use "https://testnet.data.api.ripple.com/v2/accounts/rBrf2VEjHaM4Tu7xgq1d1tRgxihiM72Q9V/transactions" but it doesn't return the result

Ripple has given only live net URL for transaction history related fetch history: "https://data.ripple.com/v2/accounts/r3kmLJN5D28dHuH8vZNUZpMC43pEHpaocV/transactions".

```
{"result":"success","count":0,"transactions":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think your issue that the testnet only keeps a limited number of previous ledgers so you probably don't have any transactions in that range. I just sent you 12 XRP and the transaction appeared after that.

https://testnet.data.api.ripple.com/v2/accounts/rBrf2VEjHaM4Tu7xgq1d1tRgxihiM72Q9V/transactions

```
{"result":"success","count":1,"transactions":[{"hash":"B49191DABF71C39E3B019020289781B2D631FED4053FCC4967E80C274A5E3EDB","ledger_index":21487677,"date":"2019-08-02T04:51:52+00:00","tx":{"TransactionType":"Payment","Flags":2147483648,"Sequence":1,"LastLedgerSequence":21487679,"Amount":"12000000","Fee":"12","SigningPubKey":"02DD0B81459EC6B0FB600B14BA89D0B8A8C85C176006FE04F13CD955FB0666EC8D","TxnSignature":"3044022006C86BEB21BDAF9E882F79D42280B95843F8DFE1D72A5688CC980A40E30E9DC402203ED5C8BDD3C44D9BB8C6FCE70E205AFFB8AA3B7F54DB7EA4207394FF6908467E","Account":"rnDNjncgPC7VbKfDwg67ZRqVVG8h5PEZ6c","Destination":"rBrf2VEjHaM4Tu7xgq1d1tRgxihiM72Q9V"},"meta":{"TransactionIndex":7,"AffectedNodes":[{"ModifiedNode":{"LedgerEntryType":"AccountRoot","PreviousTxnLgrSeq":20022602,"PreviousTxnID":"10120A1CBCE20B99EEA8CC0ED546EA06E7A3C55521C218905109C5C41FDA012E","LedgerIndex":"8B9E3C7C0623DB51864CFCEBFE50ACF4D5B74157B15EC0CCD8FDCE3D1CBF63BF","PreviousFields":{"Balance":"7037999700"},"FinalFields":{"Flags":0,"Sequence":30,"OwnerCount":0,"Balance":"7049999700","Account":"rBrf2VEjHaM4Tu7xgq1d1tRgxihiM72Q9V"}}},{"ModifiedNode":{"LedgerEntryType":"AccountRoot","PreviousTxnLgrSeq":21487668,"PreviousTxnID":"D923D58B8A2F8407F97633C250592E8156A814B50C33DC6FB53F4530EC6F4D20","LedgerIndex":"D3A1FD57ADC8F5ED8017F664E169B16E8FC6DC70E598AB6527C75DAF61C9422C","PreviousFields":{"Sequence":1,"Balance":"10000000000"},"FinalFields":{"Flags":0,"Sequence":2,"OwnerCount":0,"Balance":"9987999988","Account":"rnDNjncgPC7VbKfDwg67ZRqVVG8h5PEZ6c"}}}],"TransactionResult":"tesSUCCESS","delivered_amount":"12000000"}}]}
```